# (Pandas) correct lambda expression to sort column by value @ index position 1

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am attempting to sort `SrcWell` by the value's index position 1. I understand there is a keyword argument `key`, which is similar in behavior to `key` in `sorted`, however I receive a ValueError when attempting to sort using `key`. Here is an example CSV file to be loaded as a pandas DataFrame:

```
SrcPlate            SrcWell
PS000000123456      A4
PS000000123456      B7
PS000000123456      A7
PS000000123456      H6
PS000000123456      G6  
PS000000123456      F6
```

And a small script to sort `SrcWell` by its numerical values:

```py
import pandas as pd

worklist = pd.read_csv('worklist.csv')
print(worklist.sort_values(by="SrcWell", key=lambda x: int(x[1])))

>>> [...] ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'B7'
```

Comment: You appear to be trying to convert a non-numeric value to a numeric value.  Try skipping the `int()` part and see if that works better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using .str accessor and slicing:

```
df.sort_values(by="SrcWell", key=lambda x: x.str[1])
```

Output:

```
         SrcPlate SrcWell
0  PS000000123456      A4
3  PS000000123456      H6
4  PS000000123456      G6
5  PS000000123456      F6
1  PS000000123456      B7
2  PS000000123456      A7
```

As @Ben.T points out, per the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html)

> **key : callable, optional**
> Apply the key function to the values before
> sorting. This is similar to the key argument in the builtin sorted()
> function, with the notable difference that this key function should be
> vectorized. *It should expect a Series and return a Series with the*
> *same shape as the input.* It will be applied to each column in by
> independently.